# std::vector reallocations regardless reserved capacity when used as a stack

Tags: c++, memory, stdvector

Today I've run into rather interesting issue. I used std::vector as a stack to make recursive tree traversal algorithm iterative. To reuse vector capacity I moved it out the function to some global scope. But I didn't gain any performance improvements with this approach. I ran Clion built-in profiler to analize the issue and found out that memory reallocations still happen every function call and make my code run twice as slowly as original recursive implementation. Using static array instead of std::vector resolves the issue. But it isn't stable enough approach as I can't guarantee that its size would be enough.

I reproduced the issue with a minimum of code and linked screenshot with the profiler output. Note that printing stack.capacity() shows that capacity is preserved between function calls.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> stack;

void doSmthWithStack() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        stack.push_back(i);
    while (!stack.empty())
        stack.pop_back();
}

int main() {
    while (true)
        doSmthWithStack();
}
```

EDIT:

It's suggested to describe the profiler output with words:

It shows that during push_back and pop_back operations __annotate_increase and __annotate_shrink are called respectively. Adding up they take 60% of the runtime. As I can guess from the names these are the memory reallocations.

[Profiler output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9Lws.png)

Comment: You could have used [std::stack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) instead.

Comment: Your profile doesn’t show any memory being allocated/freed. What in it makes you think it does?

Comment: Also, if you're profiling a debug build, then this is meaningless.  You should be profiling a release, optimized build.

Comment: All questions here should have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors, shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. Please [edit] this question, removing and replacing all links and images with all relevant information as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text, please use them as an example for how your question should look.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
1. As practice shows, std::vector is usually quicker than std::stack because std::stack uses std::deque
2. And you're right, turing on the optimizations resolves the issue but capacity guarantees that compliant to the standard should remain regardless the safe compiler options.

Comment: @SemyonPanenkov *std::vector is usually quicker than std::stack because std::stack uses std::deque* -- Try to do a `pop` with a million element stack made with `std::vector`.

Comment: @MikeVine, I edited the post and pointed that memory reallocation methods are called inside std::vector. I'm sure now that they are memory reallocations because I dove into the source code and saw calls to the allocator.

Comment: As [this example shows](https://godbolt.org/z/44KKbv), addresses of `stack` elements remain the same, when printed in `doSmthWithStack` between push and pop loops. This demonstrates rather conclusively that no reallocation in fact takes place - the same chunk of memory is being reused.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, yes, you've proved your point. No reallocations actually happen. But this approach still has rather big performance penalty compared to static array. And according to profiler that's not due to cache misses but to strange calls to allocator.

Comment: Are you profiling an unoptimized build, by any chance? The only calls to allocator should be `construct` and `destroy`, but those are trivial for `int` type, and should be inlined and then optimized away in an optimized build.